# Trying do-release-upgrade on 18.04: "system is unable to reach snap store"

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I tried to upgrade 18.04.? to 20.04.1 with *sudo do-release-upgrade*. I got the error screen with s*ystem is unable to reach snap store*. I aborted and it says the *upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade process*. What should be my next move?

Comment: I've never seen that happen before. I think my first step would be to probably run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, followed by a reboot while hoping my system came back online, because I have absolutely no idea what state your computer is actually in. If it reboots, keep on truckin'. If not, well... Let's just hope that it does. It may just mean that snap apps didn't get updated.

Comment: Before rebooting a system that you're not sure will come up again, it's always a good idea to make sure you have a rescue option (usb installation media or something) available... just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: _sudo apt upgrade_ said I have LXD dependencies that need fixing first, it recommended running _apt --fix-broken install_ first. A LXD update window asked which version I wanted, 3, 4 or latest and recommended v4 which I selected. Now _apt upgrade_ is doing it's thing. I have a vm image backup.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion to run *apt update* and *apt upgrade* fixed my problem but it's also a good idea to have a backup on hand, thanks to @KGIII & @Jakke.